# Real-time updates and Graph API 2.3

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/v2.3, the way to subscribe for real-time updates is via the /{app-id}/subscriptions endpoint. But https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/app/subscriptions/ says that this endpoint is no longer available in v2.3.

Meanwhile, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/page/subscribed_apps/ talks about subscribing to a page's feed, but doesn't offer POST or DELETE operations for managing such subscriptions. Nevertheless, the changelog for v2.2 does describe GET/POST/DELETE for /{page-id}/subscribed_apps.

So, what's the current, accurate story for handling real-time updates? Is it only RTUs from pages? At very least, the documentation is confusing...and I believe it to be incorrect and conflicting with itself. Can someone clear up how to subscribe and handle RTUs in a v2.3 world?

Comment: Regarding the documentation, there is currently an open bug report about this https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1580308818919460/